# Can't mock final class in test using Mockito with Kotlin

Tags: testing, kotlin, mockito

I'm trying to run a simple instrumentation test:

```
class DefaultTest {

    private val networkHelper = Mockito.mock(NetworkHelperImpl::class.java)

    @Test fun inter() {
        given(networkHelper.isConnectedToNetwork()).willReturn(true)
        assertFalse { networkHelper.isConnectedToNetwork(false) }
    }
}
```

But i cant bacause of error:

```
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
- final class
```

How can i avoid it?

As this guide says:

https://antonioleiva.com/mockito-2-kotlin/

I'm create file:

[image]

With this line:

`mock-maker-inline`

But nothing changes.

Gradle is bad(i'm learning), but it must work. I use unit test too, so now i have:

```
//Tests
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'

testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.41'
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.3.41'

androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.24.5'
androidTestImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.1.0"

testImplementation 'org.amshove.kluent:kluent:1.14'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
```

Comment: I know this is not an answer - but for kotlin mocking I switched to https://mockk.io/ and I have not looked back. You can mock final classes, and, if you ever get in to any async suspend functions, this comes with built in tools for that. Built in kotlin for kotlin.

Answer (score 49):

Simply adding

```
testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.8.47")
```

resolved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

1. Follow this steps: https://antonioleiva.com/mockito-2-kotlin/
2. Update the libraries and replace `androidTestImplementation` with **`testImplementation`**. In my case:

   testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.1.0 (update)

   testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.0.0' (update)

   testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.24.5' (replace androidTestImplementation with testImplementation)
3. Remove  **MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)** from each Test class.

Tested with Android Studio 3.5

Comment: It happened a while for me, but in my case, I don't have a `mockito-core` dependencies

Comment: It look like that only wotks with local test, (testImplementation), i  used the dependencies by @Cristi Constantin  and works only in local test.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply because the class in Kotlin is final by default, so Mockito can't create a mock from final classes.

You can either mark a class `open` as well as individual methods you like to test.

For example

```
open class AbcClass {
    open fun foo() = print("foo")
    fun bar() = print("bar")
}
```

The class AbcClass is mockable and its `foo()` method is testable by Mockito.

I had a similar issue, this is how I resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`mockito-kotlin`](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin)?
Add this to your dependencies:

```
testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.1.0"
```

Comment: I add, but nothing changed.

Comment: Same here, could you share all dependencies which included in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're compiling Mockito only for Instrumentation tests - the ones inside `androidTest`. However, you want to do this for the unit tests according to where you've put the Mockito extension configuration.

When you use `androidTestImplementation` you're compiling that dependency for instrumentation tests. Using `testImplementation` will compile for unit tests. Replace:

```
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.24.5'
androidTestImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.1.0"
```

With:

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.0.0'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.24.5'
testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.1.0"
```

Answer (score -1):

Annotate your test class by `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)`. So your class will looked like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class DefaultTest {

    private val networkHelper = Mockito.mock(NetworkHelperImpl::class.java)

    @Test fun inter() {
        given(networkHelper.isConnectedToNetwork()).willReturn(true)
        assertFalse { networkHelper.isConnectedToNetwork(false) }
    }
}
```

For me, I worked everything as like as you did and failed. I was missed just that annotation part. After adding annotation it's working as expected.

Comment: But here the object is a spy or mock. Where we need to define that?