# Mockito cannot mock this class?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I'm writing some unit tests for my app but i'm having the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.example.outsideintddexample.Engine.
Can not mock final classes with the following settings :
 - explicit serialization (e.g. withSettings().serializable())
 - extra interfaces (e.g. withSettings().extraInterfaces(...))
```

This is the class Engine:

```
package com.example.outsideintddexample

import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay

class Engine(
    var temperature: Int = 15,
    var isTurnedOn: Boolean = false
) {

    suspend fun turnOn() {
        isTurnedOn = true
        delay(5000)
        Log.d("Teste", "Hello World")
        temperature = 95
    }
}
```

My test implementation:

```
class CarShould {

    private val engine: Engine = mock()
    private val car = Car(engine,5.0)


    @get:Rule
    var rule = MainCoroutineScopeRule()


    @Test
    fun looseFuelWhenItTurnsOn() = runBlockingTest {
        car.turnOn()

        assertEquals(4.5, car.fuel)
    }

    @Test
    fun turnOnItsEngine() = runBlockingTest {
        car.turnOn()

        verify(engine, times(1)).turnOn()
    }
```

I tried adding `unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true` into my gradle app but the error remains

I'm using  testImplementation `'com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.1.0`' and `testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.21.0'`

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536196/cant-mock-final-class-in-test-using-mockito-with-kotlin) help?

Comment: @Stachu Thanks for you comment. I updated mockito inline to 3.7.0 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this error while using "kotlinx serialization" and was able to fix it by adding this dependency:

```
testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-inline:5.2.0")
```