# Mockito cannot mock/spy because : - final class

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I am a simple function getCreditReport in viewmodel in which I am trying to make an API call repository layer
I want to test getCreditReport in viewmodel to check that thge repository is called but I get the following error

```
   org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class com.example.clearscore.data.DataRepository
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class
```

What I have tried

MainActivityViewModel

```
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    //private val retroServiceInterface: RetroServiceInterface,
    private val dataRepository: DataRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var creditReportLiveData: MutableLiveData<CreditReport>

    init {
        creditReportLiveData = MutableLiveData()
    }

    fun getCreditReportObserver(): MutableLiveData<CreditReport> {
        return creditReportLiveData
    }

    fun getCreditReport() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response = dataRepository.getCreditReport()
                creditReportLiveData.postValue(response)
                Log.d("data", response.toString())
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.d("data", e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DataRepository

```
class DataRepository @Inject constructor(
        private val retroServiceInterface: RetroServiceInterface
) {

    suspend fun getCreditReport(): CreditReport {
        return retroServiceInterface.getDataFromApi()
    }
}
```

Unit test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MainActivityViewModelTest {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var dataRepository: DataRepository

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel

    @Test
    fun getCreditReport() {
        runBlocking {
            mainActivityViewModel.getCreditReport()
            verify(dataRepository).getCreditReport()
        }
    }
}
```

Dependency Injection component - in case this is helpful

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [RetroModule::class])
interface RetroComponent {

    fun inject(mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel)

    fun getMainactivityViewModel(): MainActivityViewModel
}
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong

Thanks
R

Comment: What Mockito versions and dependencies are you using?

Comment: @aSemy dependencies are 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2"

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried adding `mockito-inline`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63233687/4161471 You could look into `mockito-kotlin` too, it improves Mockito support for Kotlin https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin

Comment: Hello I added that and it worked thank you

Answer (score 26):

Please try adding this dependency

```
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.11.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Adding to help future folks who stumble upon this question]

In my case, the class didn't need to be final so I just removed `final` from the class declaration.

Comment: the class might be in some lib, how the flip I am supposed to remove the final from it?